# How to add other languages to TeX

Tags: ubuntu, mediawiki, tex, ubuntu-9.10

In MediaWiki if you add in formulas non english text it cuts. For example if you write `\text{щfбb}` (`щ` and `б` russian (cyrillic) symbols) output will be `fb` not `щfбb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if you have MediaWiki version lower than 1.18 then open file includes/Math.php and find (this code for version 1.16):

```
escapeshellarg( $wgTmpDirectory ).' ';
escapeshellarg( $this->tex ).' ';
```

and replace with:

```
escapeshellarg( $wgTmpDirectory ).' '; setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.utf8"); $cmd .=
escapeshellarg( $this->tex ).' '; setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); $cmd .=
```

this needed because `escapeshellarg` [cut UTF8 symbols](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44945). If you see in that place function `wfEscapeShellArg` instead of `escapeshellarg` then you need to set [`$wgShellLocale`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgShellLocale) to `en_US.utf8`.

Second, download latest [Math extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMath) and extract `math` folder. Open file `texutil.ml` and find line:

```
"\\usepackage{cancel}\n\\pagestyle{empty}\n\\begin{document}\n$$\n"
```

add your alphabet:

`"\\usepackage[russian]{babel}\n\\usepackage{cancel}\n\\pagestyle{empty}\n\\begin{document}\n$$\n"`

Delete all files from your current `math` folder and upload files from extension. Open console, `cd` to `math` folder and do `make`:

```
$ aptitude install ocaml /* install ocaml if needed */
$ make
```

Also add to `LocalSettings.php` (change folder to yours):

`putenv('HOME=/home/user');`

Now new alphabet should work. `;)`