# Trying to making work russian lang in TeX

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mediawiki, tex

- Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11
- MediaWiki 1.16.5

I installed TeX themself and he works, but russian letters in `\text{}` not working, error: `Failed to parse (PNG conversion failed; check for correct installation of latex, dvips, gs, and convert)`.

If I run command (`/home/user/www/site.ru/math/texvc '/home/user/www/site.ru/images/tmp' '/home/user/www/site.ru/images/tmp' '\text{ пример }' 'utf-8' 'transparent'`) (user is same as in apache) from cmd it works! File in `/home/user/www/site.ru/images/tmp` [exists](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5214/203537249.b/0_f0717_7800f064_orig.png). And output is `cd7d4363323218b64410c10a0a2b46773 пример` . Wich proving installation is correct.

When same command executed in MediaWiki, output is similar (`cd7d4363323218b64410c10a0a2b46773 пример` ), but file doesn't exists. In `/home/user/www/site.ru/images/tmp` folder appears log `missfont.log` with this contents:

```
mktextfm larm1200
mktextfm larm0800
mktextfm larm0600
```

I'm tried to [run this commands](https://gist.github.com/1v/419bbb0fee9d4cb44fcf) but it change nothing. I even tried create [test.php](https://gist.github.com/1v/47bea3ff169d391bd82d) and test without CMS. Result is same as in MediaWiki (`missfont.log` created in temp).

PS In Ubuntu 9.10 russian lang in \text{} worked. I added in `texutil.ml` russian babel `"\usepackage[russian]{babel}\n\usepackage{cancel}\n\pagestyle{empty}\n\begin{document}\n$$\n"` and recompile sources. And did some changes in Math.php (with locals). Also I downloaded latest Math extension and replaced `math` folder. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276412/712308).

Comment: Please, please, please don't run installations that old - you're completely vulnerable to a bunch of critical security issues.

Comment: @MaxSem there is no patch from 1.16.5 to 1.17.0

Comment: Even 1.17 went out of support ages ago. Please make everyone's life easier and use  only versoions from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in system variable `HOME`. So to fix you need to add in `LocalSettings.php` line `putenv('HOME=/home/user');` (with your **user** home dir).

Comment: my life will never be the same